# Get react states name using props

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering if it is possible to get state name using `this.props`.
Example:

`this.state.(this.props.name)`

I am setting state like this:

```
  onInputChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({[e.target.name]: [value: e.target.value, error: this.props.error]})
  }
```

And `e.target.name` come from `<input name={this.props.name} />`.

I need somehow to display those states from array.

Full code below. I will add input validation there later after i figure out this step.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Input extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {

  }
 }
 onInputChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: [value: e.target.value, error: this.props.error]})
 }
 render () {
  return(
   <div className="form-group">
    <span>HERE WILL GO ERROR FROM STATE ARRAY AFTER VALIDATION</span>
    <input
     onChange={this.onInputChange}
     type={this.props.type}
     name={this.props.name}
     className="form-control input-lg"
     placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
    />
  </div>
  )
 }
}

export default Input;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue you are having? `this.state[this.props.name]` should work fine

Comment: You cannot set array elements as key value pair..

Comment: thanks, yes, this.state[this.props.name] is correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this.state[this.props.name].

I have created working code in sandbox.  Please have a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/pp3o0r2zrq

Comment: But what about getting array items ? I would guess like this: this.state[this.props.name].value but i get undefined error

Comment: Plz share proper data.. Then only I will be able To help

Comment: So this is correct way how to get array item ? this.state[this.props.name].value ?

Comment: No... If this.state[this.props.name] is an array. You can only fetch value at any index using index like 0,1,2 etc.. Can you please show me the data?

Comment: Ok thanks now i see. by data you mean code ? i updated my question with full code.

Comment: will accept your answer because it is correct anyway :)

Comment: @EdgarsŠustsPlease see the sandbox link above.. It has working code. when you type in the input box you will be able to see the data. I was not sure why you were setting error as well as its not coming from props.

Comment: thanks. error was bad example. i will use state which come from props. . i will be validating things, they come from props.